# powershell 5.1 - overwrite a file myText.txt by replacing every regex match with a newline character

Tags: newline, powershell-5.0, regexp-replace

Using powershell 5.1, why is my attempt to insert a newline at every regex match of `myText.txt` not working as i expect?

To my knowledge My regex works fine, it matches every 5th comma.

[image]

**Unfortunately The code fails to inject/replace/insert a newline at every regex match.** For some reason instead it adds a newline to the end every time i run the following statement:

To test this,

1. Given a file, `myText.txt` that trails with a `,` and looks exactly like this: `,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,`
2. Run the command below and observe the results

**$splitEveryNthComma = ((Get-Content -path .\myText.txt -Raw) -replace "(?<=^((,[^,]*){5})+),]","`n,") | Set-Content -Path .\myText.txt**

How can i change my code above to get the "expected result" below?

**Expected result of myText.txt**:

```
,1,2,3,4,5
,6,7,8,9,10
,11,12,13,14,15
,16,17,
```

**Actual result of myText.txt:**

```
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,
{new line is added to the end. This is the bug im asking about.}
```

Comment: see updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex can be simplified

```
",1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17," -replace "((,[^,]*){5})", "`$1`n"
```

gives

```
,1,2,3,4,5
,6,7,8,9,10
,11,12,13,14,15
,16,17,
```

The regex `(,[^,]*){5}` captures the first / next 5 commas (including anything after them) and appends a newline after it. The parentheses in the expression groups it for the `{5}` (the outer parentheses in the code block above is what does the capture)